# Lock screen on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, events

I'm building my app with `Phonegap`. What I want to do is create a button on the screen and add a lock-screen event `onclick`. I searches on other posts but everyone tries to check if the screen is locked and execute then or before something. I only need the event (lock screen) to happen when clicking that button. It's exactly like you would lock it from the physical button on the iPhone but only it happens by clicking a button.

I need it both for `iOS` and `Android` but if you could give me a hint for only one, is welcomed.

**Thank you!**

Comment: You cannot do this on iOS.

Comment: Oh, I was afraid of that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Android side;

As far as i know you app need to be registered on the device as an admin app. Then you can use the Device Administration API to lock the screen by DevicePolicyManager.lockNow()